# Error while running a python script on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I'm trying to run the below python script on AWS Lambda, which I have run manually and I could get the outcome on my output S3 bucket without any issue. But now when I invoke the script from AWS Lambda getting the below error, not sure if I am missing anything on the script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3

#Function for executing athena queries
def run_query(Event, context):
    ...
    run_query(query, database, s3_output)
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 's3_accesslog'
            },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': s3_output,
            }
        )
    
#import datetime 
import datetime
year = datetime.date.today()
year = year.strftime("%Y")
month = datetime.date.today()
month = month.strftime("%m")
day = datetime.date.today()
day = day.strftime("%d")

#select bucket 
s3_input = "s3://smathena/cf-ant-prod/year=%s/month=%s/day=%s" % (year, month, day)
   
#Athena configuration
s3_ouput = 's3://smathena/athenatest/'
database = 's3_accesslog'
table = 'test_output1'

#Athena database and table definition
create_database = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s;" % (database)
delete_table = "drop table %s.%s;" % (database, table)
create_table = \
  """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s.%s (
  `Date` DATE,
   Time STRING,
   Location STRING,
   SCBytes BIGINT,
   RequestIP STRING,
   Method STRING,
   Host STRING,
   Uri STRING,
   Status INT,
   Referrer STRING,
   UserAgent STRING,
   UriQS STRING,
   Cookie STRING,
   ResultType STRING,
   RequestId STRING,
   HostHeader STRING,
   Protocol STRING,
   CSBytes BIGINT,
   TimeTaken FLOAT,
   XForwardFor STRING,
   SSLProtocol STRING,
   SSLCipher STRING,
   ResponseResultType STRING,
   CSProtocolVersion STRING,
   FleStatus STRING,
   FleEncryptedFields INT,
   CPort INT,
   TimeToFirstByte FLOAT,
   XEdgeDetailedResult STRING,
   ScContent STRING,
   ScContentLen BIGINT,
   ScRangeStart BIGINT,
   ScRangeEnd BIGINT
   )
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   LOCATION '%s'
   TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count' = '2');""" % (database, table, s3_input)

#Query definitions
query_1 = "SELECT * FROM %s.%s where CAST(status AS VARCHAR) = '404';" % (database, table)

#Execute all queries
queries = [ create_database, delete_table, create_table, query_1 ]
for q in queries:
   print("Executing query: %s" % (q))
   res = run_query(q, database, s3_ouput)
```

But now when I invoke the script from AWS Lambda getting the below error, not sure if I am missing anything on the script?

```
{
  "errorMessage": "run_query() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 696, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 677, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 728, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 86, in <module>\n    res = run_query(q, database, s3_ouput)\n"
  ]
}``
```

Comment: How is this Lambda function being invoked? How is it meant to be given values for `query`, `database` and `s3_output`?

Answer (score 2):

your function, `lambda_handle`, doesn't conform to the [python lambda interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html):

```
def handler_name(event, context): 
    ...
    return some_value
```

inputs to your function should be in `event`.  Another example from that link:

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(event['first_name'], 
                                    event['last_name'])  
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```

I would expect `query`, `database`, and `s3_output` to be part of the `event` in your case.  You should probably `return` information about the executing athena query.